# PHP PDO connection with domain user

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I have created a normal PDO connection to a MSSQL Server. This works fine but now my admins change the sql
server and I got a domain user which has access to the database instead of a direct database user.

Now I always get the exception: SQLSTATE[28000] Login incorrect. (severity 2).

Is it possible to get access to the database with a domain user or just with a native database user?

```
Connection Code:
$this->db = new PDO($this->dbtype .':host='.$this->dbhost .';dbname='.$this->dbname, $this->user, $this->pw);
```

For the user I use: domain\username

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the answer but providing some extra info (driver used and connection code) will probably not hurt ;-)

Comment: BTW, the [Microsoft driver](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) apparently supports it.